# Rerun of my code makes spyder report an error

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

Im using Spyder 3.3.2 in anaconda. Ive been using it for 1 year now works perfectly. Today, weird things started happening. Everytime I run a code in fresh console it works if don't change anything and just press f5 again to rerun the code. It gives me an error.

```
File "/home/vivian/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/defusedxml/ElementTree.py", line 68, in __init__
    _XMLParser.__init__(self, html, target, encoding)

TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

I have to open a fresh console and again it will run just for one time and after it reports the same crash.

Ive tried googling, but I don't even know where to start. I uninstalled anaconda and deleted all files and spyder instances and installed it again and it keeps crashing.

What should I do? Its annoying if I have some real work to do, because i run the code a lot.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This problem was already reported by one of our users some days ago on this [Github issue](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/8776).

Until we properly fix it, I mentioned a [temporary workaround](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/8776#issuecomment-464459808) on that issue as well.

Comment: I dont have patterens in spydercostumize.py? is it because im on anaconda?

Comment: You need to update spyder-kernels, with this command: `pip install spyder-kernels==0.*`

Comment: Still no patterns in my spydercostumize.py :(

Comment: Sorry, it needs to be `pip install -U spyder-kernels==0.*`